# Can't find dynamic Xpath element

Tags: xpath, dynamic

I need your help to find and identify this element:

HTML: `<input type="tel" id="pp-DlfVWS-14" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber" class="a-input-text a-form-normal">`

Where "DlfVWS" change every refresh.
I have tried many combinations with no success and errors
for example:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'pp-']")

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the name attribute instead?
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='addCreditCardNumber']")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I received this answer when tried your answer:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='addCreditCardNumber']"}

Comment: Please share more html or url.

Comment: more html:
<div class="a-row"><div class="a-column a-span9"><div class="a-section a-spacing-none apx-add-credit-card-number"><input type="tel" id="pp-aa0gO6-14" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber" class="a-input-text a-form-normal"></div></div><div class="a-column a-span3 a-spacing-top-mini a-span-last"><div data-pmts-component-id="pp-aa0gO6-7" class="a-section a-spacing-none pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-pp-aa0gO6-7">

Comment: You can test the xpath in your browser console with the $x command. e.g ``$x("//body']")`` or
``$x("//input[@name='addCreditCardNumber']")``to see that your xpath is ok. Is the element located within an iframe? Is the element available from page render or is it dynamically loaded after page load?

Comment: I searched this on the console, `$x("//input[@name='addCreditCardNumber']")`  but  just appears when inspect element, before that, the result is null.  The element is available when I click on add credit card number, then appears the "floating window" in the center of site with the forms to fill, and the first form is which I can't locate with xpath or other method. :(

Comment: It is probably an iframe then? You can use ``driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#iframeid'))``
See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59588160/access-iframe-input-element-with-webdriver-python